# Sharepoint 2013 - PDF Documents are able to be checked out by users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, pdf, check-out

I have had an issue where PDF documents are checked out by the user - even though in the version control is set to **Require content approval for submitted items?**  and **Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?**
This happens spasmodically and only with PDF documents.

I have checked the DOCICON.xml settings are correct.  
Ex: `<Mapping Key="pdf" Value="pdficon_small.png" OpenControl="AdobeAcrobat.OpenDocuments" />`
Has anyone had experience with this issue and how it may be fixed.
I am lead to believe it is an ADOBE reader issue on certain versions. I am not sure if this is correct - could someone confirm or contest.

Comment: So, the library requires files to be checked out before they can be edited. And it requires content approval for submitted items. What is the problem? If people check out PDFs, they are doing what the library settings permit them to do. The annoying issue is that Acrobat Reader has this foolish button to "check out and open" next to the "open" button, and many people click the "check out and open" button, hence checking out the document, regardless of whether they want to change it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe reader 10 comes with SharePoint integration that has this annoyingly useless button to "check out and open" PDFs when the user clicks them. You can try and disable it with this registry hack  (run at your own risk).

To disable SharePoint integration:

1. Open the registry.
2. Go to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\ -ProductName- \ -version-\FeatureLockDown.
3. Create a key called cSharePoint.
4. Create a DWORD value called bDisableSharePointFeatures.
5. Set its value to 1.

Comment: I don't really want to touch the registry. I will keep it in mind if I cannot find a solution. Thanks teylyn